# How to push viewcontroller from appdelegate in storyboard

Tags: ios, iphone, swrevealviewcontroller

I am using [SWRevealViewController](https://github.com/John-Lluch/SWRevealViewController) in my project, and I want to open a particular controller when the app receives a notification. I have tried so many solutions but nothing works.

How can I show a specific ViewController from my AppDelegate?

```
(void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo {

    UIApplicationState appState = UIApplicationStateActive;
    if ([application respondsToSelector:@selector(applicationState)]) {
        appState = application.applicationState;
    }
    application.applicationIconBadgeNumber = 0;
    if (appState != UIApplicationStateActive) {

        SWRevealViewController *navigationController = (SWRevealViewController *)self.window.rootViewController;
        UINavigationController *nav = (UINavigationController *)navigationController;
        UIStoryboard *mainStoryboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle: nil];
        PushNotificationsVC *controller = (PushNotificationsVC*)[mainStoryboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier: @"PushNotificationsVC"];
        [nav pushViewController:controller animated:YES];

    } else {

        UIAlertView *alertView = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Notification"
                                                            message:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[[userInfo objectForKey:@"aps"] valueForKey:@"alert"]]
                                                           delegate:nil
                                                  cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"
                                                  otherButtonTitles:nil];
        [alertView show];
    }
}
```

Comment: You should read the [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) to ask good questions.

Comment: I have a slide menu in my project for that i have use SWRevealViewController component. And when i get the push notification i want to open a particular screen(ViewController). I am no able to open a particular controller from the appdelegate .(applicationDidReceiveNotification).Are you geting what i am try to saying??

Comment: If you have any idea then plz do reply

Comment: did you try this : `[self.window.rootViewController presentViewController:MyCustomViewController animated:NO completion:nil]` ? Can you show us what do you have in `-(void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo;`
 ?

Answer (score 13):

For those who following this http://www.appcoda.com/ios-programming-sidebar-navigation-menu/ by using storyboard.

```
UIStoryboard *st = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle: nil];
DestinationController *descController = (DestinationController*)[st instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier: @"storyboardID_DestController"];
UINavigationController *frontNavigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:descController];
SidebarViewController *rearViewController = (SidebarViewController*)[st instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier: @"storyboardID_SidebarMenu"];

RevealViewController *mainRevealController = [[SWRevealViewController alloc]  init];

mainRevealController.rearViewController = rearViewController;
mainRevealController.frontViewController= frontNavigationController;

self.window.rootViewController = mainRevealController;
```

Hope it help someone else...

Comment: This works for me but hides my back button since Im navigating to a child menu view controller

Answer (score 5):

Those looking for a swift answer:

```
    var storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)

    var destinationController = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("DestinationController") as? DestinationController

    var frontNavigationController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: destinationController!)

    var rearViewController = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("MenuController") as? MenuController

    var mainRevealController = SWRevealViewController()

    mainRevealController.rearViewController = rearViewController
    mainRevealController.frontViewController = frontNavigationController
    self.window!.rootViewController = mainRevealController
    self.window?.makeKeyAndVisible()
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SWRevealViewController *navigationController = (SWRevealViewController *)self.window.rootViewController;
UINavigationController *nav = (UINavigationController *)navigationController;
```

> > 

modify ---------

```
UINavigationController *nav = (UINavigationController *)navigationController.frontViewController;



UIStoryboard *mainStoryboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle: nil];
PushNotificationsVC *controller = (PushNotificationsVC*)[mainStoryboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier: @"PushNotificationsVC"];
[nav pushViewController:controller animated:YES];
```

Comment: NavigationViewController *frontNavigationController = [NavigationViewController alloc] initWithRootViewController:frontVC];
NavigationViewController *rearNavigationController = [[NavigationViewController alloc] initWithRootViewController:rearVC];
SWRevealViewController *mainRevealController = [[SWRevealViewController alloc] initWithRearViewController:rearNavigationController frontViewController:frontNavigationController];

I have found the solution Thanks everybody for the giving efforts.
I am not able to give vote up to anyone sorry.

Answer (score 0):

As the user34336439 mentioned with some word defects, the correct answer is

```
    FrontViewController *frontViewController = [[LiveScoreViewController alloc] init];
    RearViewController *rearViewController = [[RearViewController alloc] init];

    UINavigationController *frontNavigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:frontViewController];
    UINavigationController *rearNavigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:rearViewController];
    SWRevealViewController *mainRevealController = [[SWRevealViewController alloc] initWithRearViewController:rearNavigationController frontViewController:frontNavigationController];

    self.window.rootViewController = mainRevealController;
```