# SWRevealViewController and 3D Touch quickActions

Tags: swrevealviewcontroller, quickaction, 3dtouch

I have an application implementing a side menu in swift. 
(http://www.appcoda.com/sidebar-menu-swift/)

I implemented 3D touch shortcut, quick actions, it almost works.

The problem is I arrive directly on my view without instantiate revealViewController(), with the following code:

```
let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
let navVC = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("newsViewController") as! UINavigationController
self.window?.rootViewController?.presentViewController(navVC, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

I don't know how/where is instantiated revealViewController().

I have:

```
self.revealViewController() == nil
```

What happens now is the menu doesn't want to open.

Thank you for your help :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For those who want to do it with Swift:

```
let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
let frontNavigationController = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("planningViewController")
let rearNavifationController = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("menuViewController")
let mainRevealController : SWRevealViewController = SWRevealViewController(rearViewController: rearNavifationController, frontViewController: frontNavigationController)
self.window?.rootViewController? = mainRevealController
```

Answer (score 2):

You can found your answer as this link:
[How to push viewcontroller from appdelegate in storyboard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22654503/how-to-push-viewcontroller-from-appdelegate-in-storyboard)

I Worte code as below It works for me.

```
    UIStoryboard *st = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil];
    SWRevealViewController *mainRevealController = [[SWRevealViewController alloc] init];
    CaseCollectionViewController *descController = (CaseCollectionViewController*)[st instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier: @"CaseCollection"];
    descController.selectedLevel = @"pll";
    descController.title = @"PLL";

    //UINavigationController *frontNavigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:descController];
    UINavigationController *frontNavigationController = (UINavigationController*)[st instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier: @"NavigationViewCtrl"];
    [frontNavigationController setViewControllers:@[descController]];
    SidebarTableViewController *rearViewController = (SidebarTableViewController*)[st instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier: @"SideBarView"];
    mainRevealController.rearViewController = rearViewController;
    mainRevealController.frontViewController = frontNavigationController;
    self.window.rootViewController = mainRevealController;
```

Answer (score 0):

In Order to get your reveal ViewControlled you must make it as InitialViewController in storyboard, don't need to write any code in Appdelgate.

You can find the best example in [git hub storyboard example](https://github.com/John-Lluch/SWRevealViewController/tree/master/RevealControllerStoryboardExample2) 
or
set up like below screen shot
[image]

Comment: The problem is when I use 3D Touch quick actions, the application goes directly in my view I selected with quickActions, and so the application does not go neither through sw_rear nor sw_front. How can I solve that?

Answer (score 0):

**Objective-c code for deep linking.It will open the home with side menu and will push the home (front viewcontroller) to the notification viewcontroller.**

```
UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil];
UINavigationController *frontViewControllerNav = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"homeNav"];// navigation controller of home screen..
UINavigationController *rearViewControllerNav = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"sideMenuNav"];//navigation controller of menu screen..

SWRevealViewController *revealController = [[SWRevealViewController alloc] initWithRearViewController:rearViewControllerNav frontViewController:frontViewControllerNav];
revealController.delegate = self;
UIViewController *notificationView=[storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"notificationVC"];
[frontViewControllerNav pushViewController:notificationView animated:NO];
revealController.bounceBackOnOverdraw=NO;
//revealController.stableDragOnOverdraw=YES;
self.window.rootViewController = revealController;
```